# Como salvar retorno do comando java -version no cmd

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Estou com um problema ao salvar em .txt o retorno do comando "java -version" executado no cmd. Estou executando da seguinte forma:

```
java -version >> "%temp%/resultado.txt"
```

Ele cria o arquivo porém não salva o retorno no arquivo.
Qualquer outro comando um ping ou um ipconfig como por exemplo

```
ipconfig /flushdns >> "%temp%/resultado.txt"
```

ele salva normalmente.
Se alguém souber alguma alternativa, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao redirecionar saída de um aplicativo usando o símbolo `>`, mensagens de erro ainda vão imprimir na tela. Isso ocorre porque as mensagens de erro são frequentemente enviadas para o fluxo de erro padrão em vez do fluxo de saída padrão.

As saídas comandos são enviadas por duas correntes separadas. A saída normal é enviada pela padrão **STDOUT** e as mensagens de erro são enviadas pela **STDERR**.

Quando você redirecionar a saída do console usando o símbolo `>`, você está apenas redirecionando **STDOUT**. A fim de redirecionar **STDERR** você tem que especificar `2>` para o símbolo de redirecionamento. Isto seleciona a segunda corrente de saída que é **stderr**.

O Java retorna essa saída como erro por isso deve usar esse comando:

```
java -version 2> JavaVersion.txt
```

Ainda existe a possibilidade de inserir a saída no final do arquivo ao invés de sobrescrever o conteúdo utilizando dois símbolos `>` da seguinte forma.

```
java -version 2>> JavaVersion.txt
```

**Fonte:** https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado!